# What pattern for getting data from the model at any time?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

On the default WPF 4.5 template of [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) this is how data is fetched from the model:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetData(
            (item, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    // Report error here
                    return;
                }

                WelcomeTitle = item.Title;
            });
    }

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public void GetData(Action<DataItem, Exception> callback)
    {
        // Use this to connect to the actual data service

        var item = new DataItem("Welcome to MVVM Light");
        callback(item, null);
    }
}
```

That sounds great but the data is retrieved only once at construction of the view model.

How is one supposed to retrieve data that has changed after the construction is done ?

By creating properties and accessing them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is one supposed to retrieve data that has changed after the construction is done ?

Call the same function you called in your constructor at another time.
Do you have any problems doing that?

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is that a new DataItem will be returned. Is one supposed to rebuild the entire object with the current state using such approach ?

Comment: I don't know, that's up to you. To be honest, the concept of passing an action that takes an exception object instead of just catching it and having a normal method return value smells fishy, like a C coder from the 70s crawled back from his well deserved eternal rest, but this way or another, you call your model, you get another result, you work with that result.

Comment: Lol, sorry I was asleep ... I don't know why I've been thinking this, the object can have properties and be modified after all.